# remove file extension google app engine for php

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine

Im looking to remove the .php on the end of my app's webpage but im not quite sure how to do so in my app.yaml

heres an example:

```
application: MY APP
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /
 script: index.php

- url: /index.php
 script: index.php
```

But when I open up my app on my web browser, it says http:www.example.com/mypage.php

how can I get rid of the .php?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app.yaml file will not result in the URL being re-written in the browser. You can write your app.yaml file to not require the php suffix on URLs

```
handlers:

- url: /
 script: index.php

- url: /index
 script: index.php 

- url: /foo
  script: bar.php
```

Now the url /index will invoke the script index.php, /foo will invoke bar.php etc.

If you want this sort of addressing for all of your php scripts then you could do something like

```
- url: /(.+)
  script: (\1).php
```

Now the URL /foo would call the script foo.php, /bar would call the script bar.php etc.